# Drawing a hexagon board in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, jpanel, polygon

I am trying to draw board in java that is composed of hexagons. The hexagons are supposed to be touching each other and when a new row is created they are supposed to be shifted so that the center of the hexagon in the first row lines up with the left edge of the hexagon in the second row. Currently I have completed a hexagon which we have a class called Hextile to represent. I am having trouble getting the board to draw on the jpanel however. I am using two for loops to add the hextiles to an array of arrays. I am then using a paint component to paint these JButtons on (the hextiles are jbuttons). After using the for loops, I am using setBounds in order to place the hextiles in specific locations and so that they will be touching and not have any spacing in between. However the hextiles are not being drawn correctly. Only half of the hexagon is being drawn even when I change the height and width in setBounds. I am wondering if there is a way to do this without using setBounds because it seems to be cutting off the painting of the hexagon. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck and cannot figure out anything that will fix this issue.

Comment: Post sscce here with your code.